# MediaPlayer using more than once - Android

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have problem with using the same MediaPlayer more than once. I've tried `mp.stop()` but when i want again to start the same I'm using `mp.start()` but it wont want to play. Also I've tried `mp.reset()` and `mp.prepare()` ,than `mp.start()` but it wont want to play. So I I've done this:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
mp.start(); // using for the first time
mp.release(); 
// then again I'm creating
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
mp.start(); // second using, the same for more uses
```

I'm not sure if this is OK, but it works. Is this code good or I should use another solution?

Comment: check the docs the state diagram http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: If you call `reset` you would also need to set the data source again. You can use `pause` and `seekTo(0)` as an alternative. That would be most efficient, although any option you choose is likely to perform well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `mp.pause()` method instead of `mp.release()`. You can see the lifecycle of the mediaplayer here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Your code should look like this if you want to continue from where you paused:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
mp.start(); // using for the first time
mp.pause(); 

mp.start(); // second using, the same for more uses
```

If you want to play the same song, but start the song again:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
mp.start(); // using for the first time
mp.stop(); 

mp.prepare(); // second using, the same for more uses
mp.start();
```

Comment: But will start the song from start or will continue from pause?

Comment: It will continue the song from where you paused. I added an example if you want to restart the song.

Answer (score 1):

If you wan to use another data source, the correct order is the following one:

```
mp.stop()
mp.reset(); 
mp.setDataSource(PATH); 
mp.prepare(); 
mp.start();
```

Check the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) for more info about these calls.

Comment: No, it is the same song

Comment: @KiKo Even though it's the same media, you need to call `setDataSource` after calling `reset`.